# Опечатка в книге Майерса. Правило 18

Tags: c++

Наткнулся у Майерса на такой код из правила

> Правило 18: Проектируйте интерфейсы так, что их легко было
>   использовать правильно и трудно – неправильно

```
struct Day { struct Month { struct Year {
explicit Day(int d) explicit Month(int m) explicit Year(int y)
: val(d) {} : val(m) {} : val(y) {}
int val; int val; int val;
}; }; };
```

это опечатка? VS 2017 говорит так нельзя делать.

Comment: Выровняйте, пожалуйста, форматирование кода, а то читать очень трудно.

Comment: Вы явно перепечатали код неправильно.

Comment: я его явно скопировал как есть

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, это было три разных кода, написанных в три колонки...

Comment: За такие "перлы" редактору перевода, гм... должно быть стыдно :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему в оригинале структру записаны в колонки, а не сплошником.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(https://books.google.ru/books?id=Qx5oyB49poYC&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=Scott+Meyers+right+18+struct+day&source=bl&ots=KMoZALrYgU&sig=o6Vqh9XAeAJ2s8BzqsJ_jxqGv1g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio-LCCxcHaAhVH2SwKHWxcA_EQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q&f=false)